# Ping the public IP of an LTE SIM card

Tags: ip, ping, sim

For my phone(s) I have a 4G SIM card, which I mainly use on an Android phone; today, to my carrier, I requested a public IP and it works, since, to test, I installed an http server app: in facts I can connect and see phone's files from any device (eg using a browser on any computer); however, despite the fact that the public IP is present and working, I cannot ping it: if a run the `ping` command from any computer, I get "host unreachable", but from the same PC, as I've said, I can connect to the http server installed on the phone.
Why? I have to ask something to my carrier? There is some network restriction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually devices like these (like routers) have a setting to disable ping replies by default, like [this](https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/26810555/Why-can't-I-ping-my-public-ip.html) site explains.

You might be able to fix it by finding and configuring your phones wireless settings, typically under a heading like `Firewall`.

Comment: Unfortunately my phone is not rooted, so I guess that I cannot change firewall settings; maybe there is some Android's app which would be useful to bypass this restriction?

Comment: @Dave Check your devices source for applications.  We won’t be able to recommend any Android applications here tab Superuser

Comment: @Ramhound you're right. So I'm investigating thanks to the answer of 0x22fe.

Comment: @Dave If you find the answer to be satisfactory please mark it as such :)